# IPaddress failed in Azure

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kibana

In created Elasticserach on Azure. Azure created different VMs, network etc. that is needed. 
Now I created a Public IP address to log in to Kibana (*IPADRESS*:5601). But when I try to log in with the URL *IPADRESS*:5601, this error is generated:

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}
```

Can someone help me on how I can avoid this error?

Comment: what does F12 in Chrome says when you try to access it?

Comment: @DejanMarić  the console is emtpy, it doesn't show any errors

Comment: there's some authentication errors, please share your elasticsearch and kibana configuration file (.yml)

Comment: I deployed Kibana in Azure and don't know how to get the conf file. As soon as I have it I will post it here